# How do I generate random numbers between a range in cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, random-number-generator

I'm wanting to create a button that generates a string of 10 random numbers into cells, and pulls the range for these random numbers from, for instance, in `B1` and `B2`. Basically, I'm looking to use the `INDIRECT()` function in VBA. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What kind of random numbers? Decimals? Whole numbers? Have you looked at using `RAND()` or `RANDBETWEEN()`?

Comment: I have. I want it to be a button so I have better control over when the numbers are generated. I'm looking for whole numbers only. I know how to create a button that generates a number between a predefined range, but I'm looking to make it pick numbers from a user-defined range.

Comment: What do you have working so far? Have you attempted anything yet? Give it a try and share with us how it went. We will help you from there.

Answer (score 1):

Place one of the limits in **B1** and the other in **B2**

In **A1** enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(MIN($B$1,$B$2),MAX($B$1,$B$2))
```

and copy down thru **A10**

Put a button somewhere on the sheet and assign this macro to it:

```
Sub marine()
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

[image]